# Change the background color of textInput highlight (autocomplete) on react-native

Tags: react-native, autocomplete, background-color, highlight

How can I change this background color of TextInput when it got highlight from the autoCompleteType that already exists on react native?
like on this image

[image: Here is the image]

Answer (score 10):

To customize this autofill bg color, **you have to set this at android level**.

1. Create a xml file with the name of your choice, for example **autofill_highlight.xml** in **android/app/src/main/res/drawable**
2. Put this code inside :

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
   </shape>
   ```

   Here, the color set is transparent ("@android:color/transparent"), replace it with your color.
3. In **android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml**, add this line to your app theme (***make sure to provide your own file name if you don't call it autofill_highlight like in my example***)

   ```
   <resources>
        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

            <!-- ... your other theme customization ...  -->

            <!-- ADD THE FOLLOWING LINE -->
            <item name="android:autofilledHighlight">@drawable/autofill_highlight</item>

       </style>
   </resources>
   ```
4. Rebuild your application :)