# React native remove yellow background for TextInput autocomplete

Tags: react-native

I have a react native application with login, when I click on the `<TextInput />` it show the list of email ids used, which is fine. But the problem is, when I select one of the emails, at the background there is an yellow color.

I just tried this [Material UI remove the yellow background on TextField autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706919/material-ui-remove-the-yellow-background-on-textfield-autofill) which is `<TextField />` of react, but that doesn't work. Attached the screenshot. Any guess to fix it?

[image]

**Update 1**

```
const inputStyle = { WebkitBoxShadow: "0 0 0 1000px white inset" };
<TextInput {...this.props}
    ref='input'
    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
    style={[styles.valueText]}
    defaultValue={this.props.defaultValue}
    value={this.state.text}
    maxLength={this.props.maxLength}
    onFocus={() => this.setFocus()}
    onBlur={() => this.unsetFocus()}
    onChangeText={(value) => this.setText(value)}
    InputProps={{ classes: { input: inputStyle } }}
/>
```

Comment: include your text field code and style, Would be easy to track the issue.

Comment: @C.K updated the question with the `<TextInput />`

Comment: @overflow any update?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no solution if you are using expo. If you are not using expo you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59531916/change-the-background-color-of-textinput-highlight-autocomplete-on-react-nativ)

Comment: Haven't tried yet. Will try out during sometime this week. How about ios?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with expo modules. Create one in your modules folder (https://docs.expo.dev/modules/get-started/).

[image]

autofill_highlight.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:autofilledHighlight">@drawable/autofill_highlight</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="expo.modules.autofill"
>
</manifest>
```

Remove `android` folder if you have in main project. Rebuild app and run on emulator or device.

P.S. Make main java and ios files empty without Hello World methods, constants, ... I removed all expo created methods by default. Also in `src` directory. In this directory I created .gitkeep