# Remove Autofill Chrome Yellow Background Color in Mobile App React Native

Tags: react-native

I am beigner to React Native Mobile App . Develop Login Screen where i have stuck with Chrome Autofill yellow color .

```
<Input
          placeholder={placeholder}
          placeholderTextColor={
```

Style

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textInputStyle: {
```

Please let me know , how to remove autofill yellow color in react native .
Some of the post say
#1.

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
```

1. -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
   }

#2.`autocomplete="off"`
Please give some Sample link for the above issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the background color of textInput highlight (autocomplete) on react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59531916/change-the-background-color-of-textinput-highlight-autocomplete-on-react-nativ)

Answer (score 0):

In react-native we have a prop `autoCompleteType` to disable this. might below code help.

```
<TextInput
  autoCompleteType="off"
/>
```

for more help, please see https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#autocompletetype